# How set priority to intellij idea process?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to set the priority to "Below Normal" for idea64.exe process and all it descendants. I also want this setting to be retained permanently and I do not want to set it every time I run idea. Is there an IntelliJ IDEA settings for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating shortcut for below command:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "start /belownormal notepad.exe"
```

For Idea it will look like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "start /belownormal C:\"Program Files (x86)"\JetBrains\"IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1"\bin\idea64.exe"
```

Other Options:

```
/low
/belownormal
/normal
/abovenormal
/high
/realtime
```

Comment: For escaping spaces, otherwise it fails to run

Comment: it is not for each directory but for those directories which have spaces.

Comment: I've not tried that way, afaik, if whole path is quoted it would not be a path but just string... did you try? does it work?

Comment: Well, interesting it doesn't work. Never experienced something like that. But your version works. Good to know, thanks. Btw I removed my obsolete question :).

Comment: Consider using triple quotes instead: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "start """title""" /belownormal """C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1\bin\idea64.exe"""`.